# A Series convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove that $\sum_{n=l+1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2^n}} \leq C \sqrt{h\log(\frac{1}{h})}$ where $2^{-l} <h \leq 2^{-l+1}$?.

Comment: Two. Just write it as $(1/2+1/4+\ldots) + (1/4+1/8+\ldots)+(\ldots)+\ldots$

Comment: @PeterFranek: I want to know the tail sum from $k$.

Comment: Same method works as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330493/how-do-you-prove-sum-frac-n2n-2

Comment: Marked as duplicate

Comment: If you start with $k$, just start with the $k$'th of my parenthesis.. what is the sum?

Comment: @PeterFranek: Sorry. I completely missed the square root. P. check

Comment: @Sosha With the square root, I doubt that you can find an expression in closed form. (But I don't know)

Comment: @PeterFranek: i posted the original problem. i need upper bound. if you upper bound $\sqrt{n}$ by $n$ then the earlier method work , but it won't give the desired bound, it will give only  $\sqrt{h}$

Comment: @Sosha I recommend to post a new problem and ask a clear question without changing it then too much. It just needs time to prepare it.. Also, don't forget to include your attempts.