# Sum of the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum of the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}$ is

$a.1$

$b.2$

$c.3$

$d.4$

With which known series I have to compare the given series? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: own thoughts???

Comment: Actually, this is not a duplicate as one of the questions is "With which known series i have to compare".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right, rather "not a real question" since we do not know what "known series" mean to the OP.

Comment: @Did: that's precisely the question I guess, for a comparison test.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but the OP is supposed to know their own curriculum and the corresponding list of "known series" while we are not.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330493/how-do-you-prove-sum-frac-n2n-2 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788459/sum-of-the-series-sum-fracn2n/1788477#1788477

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$${\frac {x}{(1-x)^{2}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$
let $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to get what you want

Comment: yes i got the point... Thanks a lot..

Comment: you are welcome